# MySQL Workbench does not display captions on the canvas

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the latest version of MySQL Workbench. However, when I add relationships, go to the relationship editor and add `Caption` it is not displaying it in the canvas. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `Preferences/Diagram/Hide Captions`. In MySQL Workbench 6.2 and newer this is under `Preferences/Modeling/Diagram/Hide Captions`.